# Differences between matt and silk paint

Tags: paint, materials

I have started to paint my new home in matt as i prefer the none reflective surface compared to silk.

My Grandfather has said i should always paint walls with silk, but my outlaws say matt is just as good.

What are the actual differences other than the look of the paint?

Answer (score 2):

Paints, in order of shininess from least to most, go:
Flat-Matte-Eggshell-Satin-Semi Gloss-Gloss-High Gloss

10+ years ago:
The reason shinier paints are shinier is because they have a greater concentration of binding agents (adhesives). Because greater amounts of adhesives provides a sturdier paint, glossier paints are more durable and washable than flatter paints.

Satin is generally considered a good middle-ground. It's flat enough to not show tiny imperfections but strong enough to endure washing.

Today:
As the chemicals in paints have evolved, flatter paints have become more durable and washable (provided you're dealing with a quality paint).  I'd wager the adhesives in matte paint today do a better job of binding the material than the adhesives you could find in a gloss paint from the 1990s.

Today, it's just a question of:
How shiny do you want your paint to be, keeping in mind that the shiner it is the more imperfections it will show?

(Personal note: I'm pretty thrilled by this development. I never liked shiny paint and just a few weeks ago painted my kitchen with Sherwin-Williams Duration matte turquoise.  Duration is one of their lines that offers washable mattes, and S-W has a very good track record to their name.)

Comment: You forgot to mention where "Silk" comes on the list! According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloss_and_matte_paint) it comes between Satan and Semi Gloss.

Comment: Just seen my typo, was tempted to correct it... but thought it was funnier to leave it! I of course meant Satin, and do not imply that it has anything to do with the devil...

Comment: I'm not saying "Silk" isn't a thing, but Hallman-Lindsay and Sherwin-Williams don't offer any paints in "Silk".  

I'd wager it's actually a manufacturer description and the wiki contributor didn't know that, because ime, it's not an industry standard.  I know S-W has a bunch of their own and several lesser-used.  e.g. velvet, low/medium lustre.

But hey, I'm not a professional painter so I could be wrong.

Comment: I just figured it was relevant, seeing as the OP only mentioned matt and silk. Silk is a common name in the UK.

Comment: Neat. I was not aware of that.